# Is this correct usage of TransactionSope?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, transactionscope

I have decided to try using a `TransactionScope`, rather than the `SqlTransaction` class.

The following is my code, wrapped in a `TransactionScope`:

```
using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        if (listParameters != null && listParameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string currentKey in listParameters.Keys)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(currentKey, GetDictionaryValue(listParameters, currentKey)));
            }
        }

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dtResults.Load(reader);
        }
    }

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

The code works, however I am not binding the `MySqlCommand` `cmd` object with a transaction at any point.  Is this a problem?

Comment: If you are not using threads, i dont see any problem :)

Comment: @Jan'splite'Kondelík My biggest concern is that when I was using an SqlTransaction object, I used to specifically pass this object into the MySqlCommand object's parameters. But with this new scope object, there is none of this. Does the transaction execute as it is supposed to like this, so?

Comment: As GSerg wrote in answer, i overlooked you are not creating connection (+1 to his answer ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the correct use.

The correct use is to create a connection after creating TransactionScope. Then the connection will detect the ambient TransactionScope and enlist itself.

```
using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
  using (var connection = new MySqlConnection())
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

If you create the connection before the scope, that connection will be out of that scope, even if you create the command after creating the scope.

Also note that TransactionScope defaults to Serializable level of isolation. This is the most secure level, but also the least concurrent one. You often want to explicitly set a more common isolation level:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(
             TransactionScopeOption.Required,
             new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted  }))
{ 

}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for.  Could you kindly elaborate on the last code snippet, as I have not understood completely?

Comment: The scope controls the [transaction isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html). Using the default constructor of `TransactionScope` is like using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`. You often don't want that (provided you know what you're doing; because otherwise Serializable might actually do you good). The common level of isolation is `READ COMMITTED`. You request that level using this overload of TransactionScope constructor.