# How does ctx.SaveChanges() affect return View("Action", model) vs return RedirectToAction("Action")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with two actions.  One action is simply a post that updates the database.  The other is the view model.  However in my action that updates the database I return it back to the original view with the view model.

```
public ActionResult ManageMxieUsers()
        {

            var model = from el in aphdb.view_EmployeeList
                        join p in aphdb.MxieCallRevPermissions on el.Id equals p.AspNetUserUserID into gj
                        from sub in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new vm_ManageMxieUsers { Id = el.Id, UserName = el.UserName, PermissionLevel = sub.PermissionLevel, MxieCallRevPermCustomList = aphdb.MxieCallRevPermCustomList.Where(w => w.PermissionID == sub.PermissionID ) };

            ViewBag.EmployeeList = aphdb.view_EmployeeList.OrderBy(o => o.UserName);

            return View(model);
        }
```

This part works perfectly.

Here is my post method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ManageMxieUsers(string userID, Int16 permissionLevel, List<string> customUserList)
        {
            var UserToEdit = aphdb.MxieCallRevPermissions.Where(w => w.AspNetUserUserID == userID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (UserToEdit == null)
            {
                MxieCallRevPermissions addPerm = new MxieCallRevPermissions();

                addPerm.AspNetUserUserID = userID;
                addPerm.PermissionLevel = permissionLevel;

                aphdb.MxieCallRevPermissions.Add(addPerm);
                aphdb.SaveChanges();

                if (permissionLevel == 3)
                {
                    foreach (var id in customUserList)
                    {
                        MxieCallRevPermCustomList list = new MxieCallRevPermCustomList();

                        list.PermissionID = addPerm.PermissionID;
                        list.AspNetUserID = id;

                        aphdb.MxieCallRevPermCustomList.Add(list);

                    }
                }

                aphdb.SaveChanges();

                @ViewBag.Success = true;
            }
            else
            {
                UserToEdit.PermissionLevel = permissionLevel;

                aphdb.SaveChanges();

                if (permissionLevel == 3)
                {
                    // Remove old custom list
                    var customList = aphdb.MxieCallRevPermCustomList.Where(w => w.PermissionID == UserToEdit.PermissionID).ToList();
                    aphdb.MxieCallRevPermCustomList.RemoveRange(customList);
                    aphdb.SaveChanges();

                    foreach (var id in customUserList)
                    {
                        MxieCallRevPermCustomList list = new MxieCallRevPermCustomList();

                        list.PermissionID = UserToEdit.PermissionID;
                        list.AspNetUserID = id;

                        aphdb.MxieCallRevPermCustomList.Add(list);

                    }

                    aphdb.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Remove old custom list
                    var customList = aphdb.MxieCallRevPermCustomList.Where(w => w.PermissionID == UserToEdit.PermissionID).ToList();
                    aphdb.MxieCallRevPermCustomList.RemoveRange(customList);
                    aphdb.SaveChanges();
                }

                aphdb.SaveChanges();

                @ViewBag.Success = true;
            }

            //aphdb.SaveChangesAsync(); // Testing ot make sure SaveChanges fired before this code.

            var model = from el in aphdb.view_EmployeeList
                        join p in aphdb.MxieCallRevPermissions on el.Id equals p.AspNetUserUserID into gj
                        from sub in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new vm_ManageMxieUsers { Id = el.Id, UserName = el.UserName, PermissionLevel = sub.PermissionLevel, MxieCallRevPermCustomList = aphdb.MxieCallRevPermCustomList.Where(w => w.PermissionID == sub.PermissionID) };

            ViewBag.EmployeeList = aphdb.view_EmployeeList.OrderBy(o => o.UserName);

            //return RedirectToAction("ManageMxieUsers"); // WORKS
            return View("ManageMxieUsers", model); // ERROR NULL on AspNetUser
        }
```

Now when I simply `return View("ManageMxieUsers", model);` The error comes back saying AspNetUsers is null.  However when I reload this page it works just fine.  When I `return RedirectToAction("ManageMxieUsers");` I get no error, but of course I lose my `ViewBag`.

My only guess is that `aphdb.SaveChanges()` is not reflected instantly? Even tho I can perform a SQL query to the database and see the data has indeed been added/updated.  As is referenced by reloading the current page.

So I'm at a loss as to why during this post method my view model portion comes up with null entries, but when I reload it they are populated normally.

I'm fine with leaving it as RedirectToAction, but would like to maybe understand better as to why this behavior is making it work.

Here is the view portion that breaks

```
<tbody>
    @{ int? permissionLevel; }
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        permissionLevel = user.PermissionLevel ?? 4;
        <tr>
            <td>@user.Id</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="mr5 selectUser" data-toggle="modal" data-userid="@user.Id" data-username="@user.UserName" data-permissionlevel="@user.PermissionLevel" data-target=".bs-example-modal-panel">@user.UserName</a>
            </td>
            <td>@permissionLevel</td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var customUser in user.MxieCallRevPermCustomList)
                {
                    @("[" + customUser.AspNetUsers.FirstName + " " + customUser.AspNetUsers.Lastname + "] ")
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

the `customUser.AspNetUsers = null` when I use `return View("ManageMxieUsers", model);` in my `[HttpPost]` method.

Comment: What is `MxieCallRevPermCustomList` on your context?

Comment: So you have a global context, `aphdb`, that is always opened, and you query it from controllers and from views (because when you say `ViewBag.EmployeeList = aphdb.view_EmployeeList.OrderBy(o => o.UserName);` the query will not be executed until someone uses `ViewBag.EmployeeList`). Don't do that. Create and dispose contexts in the controller, in each method.

Comment: @B.Yaylaci AspNetUSers is auto populated through public Virtual on the class definitions.  My concern is it doesn't work when I just return View.  But when I reload the page it works just fine (exact same code to the exact same page).

Comment: It might be the evil EF caching issue. Even though you have new data in the DB EF refuses to go to the DB to get what's actually there. Instead it uses a cache that it has previously created. If you are not working with a graph of data (an entity with navigation propeties) you can try Context.Entry<T>(entity).Reload(); otherwise you may need to mess with disposing and recreating the context, or making use of .AsNoTracking();  This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177491/how-to-force-entity-framework-to-always-get-updated-data-from-the-database

Comment: @GSerg What would the best practice be?  I've always opened it up globally at the top of my controller.  Just open it up with a using statement in each place it is needed?  I remember doing that at one point and it made some things difficult.  But it was awhile ago so I forgot why I switched to this method.

Comment: Yes, open in each place with `using`. If doing several related actions, [use a `TransactionScope`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32308733/11683) as well. If you are not using a transaction scope, note that if you also don't manually `.Open()` the context's `Connection`, then each action you perform will be treated as a separate batch (the context will call [sp_reset_connection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/596365/11683) after each method call).

Comment: @Michael Thanks for that link, I will try and change it, but it does sound like it is caching.